# realmd domain join with kinit in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, active-directory, kerberos

I’m trying to set up an Ubuntu 18.04 machine and joining it to an Active Directory domain. Previously (e. g. on Ubuntu 17.10) I could do

> ```
> # kinit -kt /path/to/keytab my_username
> # realm join ad.example.com
> ```

However, with Ubuntu 18.04, it seems that the `realm` command doesn’t see the Kerberos ticket:

> ```
> # kinit -kt /path/to/keytab my_username
> # realm join --verbose ad.example.com
>  * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.ad.example.com
>  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.A.B.150
>  * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: 10.C.D.131
>  * Successfully discovered: ad.example.com
> Password for Administrator:
>  * Unconditionally checking packages
>  * Resolving required packages
>  * LANG=C /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain ad.example.com --domain-realm AD.EXAMPLE.COM --domain-controller 10.A.B.150 --login-type user --login-user Administrator --stdin-password
>  * Using domain name: ad.example.com
>  * Calculated computer account name from fqdn: PCTEST
>  * Using domain realm: ad.example.com
>  * Sending netlogon pings to domain controller: cldap://10.A.B.150
>  * Received NetLogon info from: ADS2.ad.example.com
>  * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-liolnd/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-032njz
>  ! Couldn't authenticate as: Administrator@AD.EXAMPLE.COM: Preauthentication failed
> adcli: couldn't connect to ad.example.com domain: Couldn't authenticate as: Administrator@AD.EXAMPLE.COM: Preauthentication failed
>  ! Failed to join the domain
> ```

What could be happening here? Is there something obvious I’m missing (e. g. some package is not installed)?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem? I have the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @Alex Not so far, unfortunately. Since the number of machines which I administer is rather small, I resorted to simply running `realm join -U my_username ad.example.com` and entering my password manually.